# Override UIColor's isEqual: method within Category

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicolor

I am trying to override the `UIColor` `isEqual:` method. I am doing so within a category method, however it does not seem to get called, either from `NSArray`'s `containsObject:`, or even when called directly, as shown below.

It has been exposed as a method in the category's header file and I have also checked that the category has been imported to the implementation file I am working on.

Where it is being called directly:

```
UIColor *col = [UIColor eightBitColorWithRed:pxl.red green:pxl.green blue:pxl.blue];
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < self.colorArrayM.count; i++) {
    if ([col isEqual:((UIColor*)self.colorArrayM[i])]) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

And the category methods:

```
-(BOOL) isEqual:(id)otherColor {
    if (otherColor == self)
        return YES;
    if (!otherColor || ![otherColor isKindOfClass:[self class]])
        return NO;
    return [self isEqualToColor:otherColor];
}

-(BOOL) isEqualToColor:(UIColor*)otherColor {
    if (self == otherColor)
        return YES;

    unsigned char r0, r1, g0, g1, b0, b1;
    [self eightBitRed:&r0 green:&g0 blue:&b0];
    [otherColor eightBitRed:&r1 green:&g1 blue:&b1];

    return r0 == r1 && g0 == g1 && b0 == b1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that categories are not intended to override existing methods:

> Although the Objective-C language currently allows you to use a category to override methods the class inherits, or even methods declared in the class interface, you are strongly discouraged from doing so. A category is not a substitute for a subclass. There are several significant shortcomings to using a category to override methods:
>
> - When a category overrides an inherited
>     method, the method in the category
>     can, as usual, invoke the inherited
>     implementation via a message to `super`.
>     However, if a category overrides a
>     method that exists in the category's
>     class, there is no way to invoke the
>     original implementation.
> - A category cannot reliably override methods declared in another category of the same class.
>
>   This issue is of particular significance because many of the Cocoa classes are implemented using categories. A framework-defined method you try to override may itself have been implemented in a category, and so which implementation takes precedence is not defined.
> - The very presence of some category methods may cause behavior changes across all frameworks. For example, if you override the `windowWillClose:` delegate method in a category on NSObject, all window delegates in your program then respond using the category method; the behavior of all your instances of NSWindow may change. Categories you add on a framework class may cause mysterious changes in behavior and lead to crashes.

You will need to swizzle the original `isEqual:` method to use your own implementation.  There is a great [NSHipster article on swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) that should get you started.

Comment: Tried swizzling and it _seemed_ to switch the implementations, i.e. `method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)` was called, however when calling `isEqual:` on the color, no logs from my custom method were printed, nor did it stop at any breakpoints... (not sure if the swizzling would mess this up?).

I ended up adding a category on NSArray for `containsColor:` and `indexOfColor:` which calls my custom method from my UIColor category.